# How can I fix maven_artifact ZIP download task in Ansible?

Tags: maven, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have two Jenkins pipelines. The first one is building a project with Maven.
One of the plugins creates a ZIP of some scripts.

Here is the *pom.xml* part

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>script</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>script-${project.version}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/script.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The *script.xml* specify the directory to ZIP and files to exclude

```xml
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/scripts</directory>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
        <directoryMode>755</directoryMode>
        <fileMode>755</fileMode>
         <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>
            **/*.log
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

At the end of the build, the `artifactPublisher` publish the ZIP to a Nexus repository with a `mvn deploy`.
Here is the log:

```
[withMaven] artifactsPublisher - Archive artifact target/checkout/target/script-2.0.0-script.zip under com/company/artifact_id/2.0.0/artifact_id-2.0.0-script.zip
```

Now I have a deploy pipeline that needs to download this artifact with Ansible.
Here is the task to the download the ZIP

```yaml
- maven_artifact:
    group_id: "{{maven_grpid}}"
    artifact_id: artifact_id
    extension: zip
    version: "{{ zip_version }}"
    repository_url: "{{ nexus_repo }}"
    username: "{{ nexus_user }}"
    password: "{{ nexus_password }}"
    dest: '{{ install_path }}/script/artifact_id-{{ zip_version }}-script.tmp'
    verify_checksum: change
    mode: '0770'
    validate_certs: false
  become: yes
```

This fails because it doesn't build the correct URL to the ZIP file

```
Failed to download artifact com.company:artifact_id:zip:2.0.0 because of HTTP Error 404: com/company/artifact_id/2.0.0/artifact_id-2.0.0.zipfor URL https://nexus_url/repository/maven-releases/com/company/artifact_id/2.0.0/artifact_id-2.0.0.zip
```

The correct url of the file is:

```
https://nexus_url/repository/maven-releases/com/company/artifact_id/2.0.0/artifact_id-2.0.0-script.zip
```

as shown in the `artifactPublisher` part.

I tried tweaking the version in Ansible with `{{ zip_version }}-script`, the filename is, then, correct, but the version in the URL gets messed up with it.

How do I fix that? Can I tweak the filename in the Ansible task?
Or maybe there is a way to change the artifact name that is published?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good thing with Ansible being an open sourced tool is the fact that you can have a peak at the code.

In this case, the file representing this module can be found in the [`community.general` collection repository](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/d1d9895eb675f17fa97269149a28869a52482ca7/plugins/modules/maven_artifact.py).

With this, we can now find the way Ansible it building the URL in the method [`_uri_for_artifact`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/d1d9895eb675f17fa97269149a28869a52482ca7/plugins/modules/maven_artifact.py#L486).
And this is probably the most interesting lines of the said method for your use case:

```py
if artifact.classifier:
    return posixpath.join(self.base, artifact.path(), artifact.artifact_id + "-" + version + "-" + artifact.classifier + "." + artifact.extension)
```

Going back to the documentation, we can see that you just have to specify a [`classifier`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/maven_artifact_module.html#parameter-classifier) to be build in your URL.

So your missing part is

```yaml
classifier: script
```

---

Which lead you to a task being

```yaml
- maven_artifact:
    group_id: "{{ maven_grpid }}"
    artifact_id: artifact_id
    classifier: script
    extension: zip
    version: "{{ zip_version }}"
    repository_url: "{{ nexus_repo }}"
    username: "{{ nexus_user }}"
    password: "{{ nexus_password }}"
    dest: '{{ install_path }}/script/artifact_id-{{ zip_version }}-script.tmp'
    verify_checksum: change
    mode: '0770'
    validate_certs: false
  become: yes
```